# Creating views in SQL and receiving error

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I know that this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the code so I don't get this error:

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Here is the code:

```
CREATE VIEW BOOK_INVENTORY (BRANCH_NUM, UNITS) AS    
SELECT BRANCH_NUM, ON_HAND 
FROM BRANCH, INVENTORY
WHERE BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
GROUP BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
ORDER BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM;
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you need to specify from which table you want `BRANCH_NUM` like:

```
CREATE VIEW BOOK_INVENTORY (BRANCH_NUM, UNITS) AS    
SELECT BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM, ON_HAND 
FROM BRANCH, INVENTORY
WHERE BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
GROUP BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
ORDER BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM;
```

Also, you might want to consider using the post ANSI SQL-92 syntax for joins like so:

```
CREATE VIEW BOOK_INVENTORY (BRANCH_NUM, UNITS) AS    
SELECT BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM, ON_HAND 
FROM BRANCH
INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
GROUP BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM
ORDER BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM;
```

See [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs][1] for some reasoning about it.
[1]: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1):

you are making `SELECT BRANCH_NUM, ON_HAND` without determine those columns from which tables. May be one of them exists in both tables, modify it for example to

```
SELECT INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM, INVENTORY.ON_HAND 
-- ...
```

of those columns from inside  INVENTORY table).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW BOOK_INVENTORY (BRANCH_NUM, UNITS) AS    
SELECT BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM, INVENTORY.ON_HAND 
FROM BRANCH, INVENTORY
WHERE BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM = INVENTORY.BRANCH_NUM
GROUP BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM, INVENTORY.ON_HAND 
ORDER BY BRANCH.BRANCH_NUM;
```

PS this query does not make much sense - why are you grouping? Also you are joining two tables for no apparent reason. The only thing this does is exclude invalid BRANCH's

Comment: Sorry, missed that - I'll change it

Comment: Thanks it works now. And this is for a class and it was in the instructions. I think we will use the grouping a little down the line in the assignment or something I'm not positive.